# what firewall linux distro applicance could track internet usage per device in my home?

Tags: linux, proxy, firewall, bandwidth

Anyone know of a community edition/open source/free firewall/gateway software product that I could install onto an old PC to act as my firewall/gateway/proxy etc, BUT for which it has the power to track internet usage per device in my home.  So:

a) Mandatory - Track internet usage for devices on my home network on a per device basis (e.g. various PCs/Xbox etc)

b) Mandatory - Report/graph would would give a breakdown of internet usage, per device (e.g. IP address), per day.

c) Desirable - as in b) above but per hour

d) Desirable - realtime graph (e.g. 5 minute measurement intervals or something) that shows current internet usage per device

e) Mandatory - Handles all internal<=>internet requests for all protocols (e.g. HTTP, HTTPS, xbox etc)

f) Mandatory - No explicit settings in clients required - i.e. Transparent Monitoring concept (for both HTTP and non-HTTP traffic like xbox, skype etc)

g) Mandatory - easy "appliance" like installation onto a dedicated low spec PC

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pfSense](http://www.pfsense.com/) with the ntop package comes very close to what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks (hadn't noted this was transfered to this site) - I can't quite see on the pfSense screen shots a graph/table that shows internet traffic use versus home device/pc?  do you know if it has such a view?

Comment: The stock pfSense does not do per-device tracking. As I mentioned, however, the ntop package will add that functionality.